# Atrributes Selection Not working on Android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, attributes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with attributes (PrestaShop 1.6)

http://www.laddersukdirect.co.uk/telescopic-ladders/abbey-telescopic-ladders.html

If you click on Choose Size: from any browser but an android browser it works as it should.

BUT if you click on Choose Size: from an android browser it opens the options to select from then closes it straight away.

Anyone else have this problem if so have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrestaShop uses jQuery Uniform plugins to style up it's inputs. This plugin actually generates some divs that show the selected information and hides the actual input (opacity = 0). You should try inspecting the amrkup and you'll see what I'm talking about.

I think you have two options:

1. Trying to disable Uniform plugin from styling up that select element - either by calling some "undo" function (you should look up the documentation) or by removing the class from that triggers the plugin (I'm actually just guessing here)
2. Modifying `product.tpl` - replacing current select element with a basic select element (which I assume works on Android)
3. You can also use jQuery: remove the overlay element, and set opacity for select element back to 1. (I don't really recommend this method)

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you very much, editing the product.tpl file was indeed the way to go.
It seems that the select form_control is not functioning properly with the explorer for mobile phones (it was working perfectly for Google Chrome on mobiles though).

This is a solution for your problem:
Open up product.tpl inside your themes folder and look for:

```
<select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
```

And comment out form-control after class so it looks like:

```
<select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="attribute_select no-print">
```

Then to add your global.css file inside your {your_theme}/css
Add the following to make it look go again:

```
select#group_3.attribute_select {width: 60%!important;}
select#group_1.attribute_select {width: 60%!important;}
```

The numbers after group vary per website, so take a look which group number is being used for you attribute selector.